# Recreating formatting of an Excel table using simplecsv

Tags: tables, formatting, csv, csvsimple

I'm trying to recreate a wholesale price list in LaTeX so that the data can be updated automatically from CSV files.

I'm able to import data using `\csvautolongtable` but I'm struggling with the formatting. This will be shown to customers as well as used internally so I would like it to look at least as good as the Excel tables the data originally came from (below):

[image]

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a way to recreate a table with similar (ideally better) formatting using csvsimple? Particularly the wrapping of long lines, prices in bold and center-aligned headers.

   Wrapping is especially important because otherwise I need to set the font to a tiny size or the table doesn't fit on the page. I'm using longtable because some other data fills more than one page.
2. Prices are in GBP, how do I get csvsimple to read the £ symbols in the CSV files? It's currently ignoring them.

Here is the CSV (technically semi-colon separated) file I'm working with:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{olive_oil_data.csv}
Code;Product Name;Unit Size;Pack Size;Unit Price
1463;AGULLO OLIVE OIL (Valencia , good value and fruity using Picual, Arbequina, Cornicabra and Chancló olives) ;5 litre;3;£17.00
1489;CAL MAS EXTRA VIRGEN OIL (Valencia, artisan single estate using Blanqueta and Alfafara olives );750ml;12;£8.52
3001;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);5 litre;3;£20.25
3002;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);2 litre;6;£8.33
3003;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL  (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );1 litre;15;£4.13
3008;MAIMONA OLIVE OIL GLASS (Extramadura,  intense green colour using Morisca olives);750ml;12;£3.86
3004;MAIMONA OLIVE OIL TIN (Extramadura, intense green colour using Morisca olives);5 litre;4;£23.91
3016;MAS D'EN GIL OLIVE OIL (Priorat, artisan delicate taste using Arberquina olives );500ml;6;£8.57
3011;MOLINO OLIVE OILGLASS (Andalucia, unfiltered fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );750ml;6;£4.85
3009;MOLINO OLIVE OIL TIN (Andalucia unfiltered fruity, Hojiblanca  Picual olives);5 litre;3;£22.10
3019;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );5 litre;3;£26.93
3020;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL (Andalucia , organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);2 litre;6;£11.03
1331;CAPIRETE PICUAL OLIVE OIL (Jaen, single estate high expression oil);500ml;12;£5.77
3021;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL GLASS  (Andalucia, Andalucia, organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );1 litre;12;£6.21
\end{filecontents*}
```

I know it's good practice to provide a MWE, so far all I have is this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\section*{Olive Oil}
    \csvautolongtable[
    before reading=\footnotesize,
    late after line=\\\hline, 
    late after last line=, 
    after reading=\normalsize,
    separator=semicolon,
    respect and=true]
    {./olive_oil_data.csv}
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thank you for providing a MWE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the pounds symbol, there has to be some file encoding chosen. If you are in the Windows world, you may have cp1252 encoded files (?).

In my answer, I assume this encoding and use `latin1` on `inputenc`.
If you use UTF-8, this setting has to be changed.

The following code tries to rebuild your screenshot (but in black and white so far).

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{olive_oil_data.csv}
Code;Product Name;Unit Size;Pack Size;Unit Price
1463;AGULLO OLIVE OIL (Valencia , good value and fruity using Picual, Arbequina, Cornicabra and Chancló olives) ;5 litre;3;£17.00
1489;CAL MAS EXTRA VIRGEN OIL (Valencia, artisan single estate using Blanqueta and Alfafara olives );750ml;12;£8.52
3001;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);5 litre;3;£20.25
3002;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);2 litre;6;£8.33
3003;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL  (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );1 litre;15;£4.13
3008;MAIMONA OLIVE OIL GLASS (Extramadura,  intense green colour using Morisca olives);750ml;12;£3.86
3004;MAIMONA OLIVE OIL TIN (Extramadura, intense green colour using Morisca olives);5 litre;4;£23.91
3016;MAS D'EN GIL OLIVE OIL (Priorat, artisan delicate taste using Arberquina olives );500ml;6;£8.57
3011;MOLINO OLIVE OILGLASS (Andalucia, unfiltered fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );750ml;6;£4.85
3009;MOLINO OLIVE OIL TIN (Andalucia unfiltered fruity, Hojiblanca  Picual olives);5 litre;3;£22.10
3019;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );5 litre;3;£26.93
3020;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL (Andalucia , organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);2 litre;6;£11.03
1331;CAPIRETE PICUAL OLIVE OIL (Jaen, single estate high expression oil);500ml;12;£5.77
3021;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL GLASS  (Andalucia, Andalucia, organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );1 litre;12;£6.21
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

% Encoding (e.g. Windows Cp1252)
% Has to be changed for UFT-8, if used
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{lmodern}% could be left out or chanaged to another font

\newcommand*{\headentry}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{#1}{\centering\arraybackslash\bfseries #2}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Olive Oil}

\csvreader[
  separator=semicolon,
  before table=\sffamily\small,
  longtable={|r|p{10cm}|r|r|r|},
  table head={\hline%
    \headentry{|m{1.8cm}|}{PRODUCT\linebreak CODE}
    & \headentry{m{10cm}|}{PRODUCT NAME}
    & \headentry{m{1cm}|}{UNIT\linebreak SIZE}
    & \headentry{m{1cm}|}{PACK\linebreak SIZE}
    & \headentry{m{2.2cm}|}{WHOLESALE\linebreak UNIT PRICE}\\\hline},
  late after line=\\\hline,
]
{./olive_oil_data.csv}
{Code=\code,Product Name=\name,Unit Size=\unitsize,Pack Size=\packsize,Unit Price=\unitprice}
{\code & \name & \unitsize & \packsize & \unitprice}

\end{document}
```

Using the `booktabs` package gives maybe some more pleasing results. See the following example code:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{olive_oil_data.csv}
Code;Product Name;Unit Size;Pack Size;Unit Price
1463;AGULLO OLIVE OIL (Valencia , good value and fruity using Picual, Arbequina, Cornicabra and Chancló olives) ;5 litre;3;£17.00
1489;CAL MAS EXTRA VIRGEN OIL (Valencia, artisan single estate using Blanqueta and Alfafara olives );750ml;12;£8.52
3001;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);5 litre;3;£20.25
3002;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);2 litre;6;£8.33
3003;GOMEOLIVA OLIVE OIL  (Andalucia, smooth and fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );1 litre;15;£4.13
3008;MAIMONA OLIVE OIL GLASS (Extramadura,  intense green colour using Morisca olives);750ml;12;£3.86
3004;MAIMONA OLIVE OIL TIN (Extramadura, intense green colour using Morisca olives);5 litre;4;£23.91
3016;MAS D'EN GIL OLIVE OIL (Priorat, artisan delicate taste using Arberquina olives );500ml;6;£8.57
3011;MOLINO OLIVE OILGLASS (Andalucia, unfiltered fruity using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );750ml;6;£4.85
3009;MOLINO OLIVE OIL TIN (Andalucia unfiltered fruity, Hojiblanca  Picual olives);5 litre;3;£22.10
3019;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL (Andalucia, organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );5 litre;3;£26.93
3020;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL (Andalucia , organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives);2 litre;6;£11.03
1331;CAPIRETE PICUAL OLIVE OIL (Jaen, single estate high expression oil);500ml;12;£5.77
3021;ORGANIC OLIVE OIL GLASS  (Andalucia, Andalucia, organic using Hojiblanca and Picual olives );1 litre;12;£6.21
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

% Encoding (e.g. Windows Cp1252)
% Has to be changed for UFT-8, if used
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array,booktabs,xcolor}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{lmodern}% could be left out or chanaged to another font

\newcommand*{\headentry}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{m{#1}}{\centering\arraybackslash\textcolor{red!85!black}{\bfseries #2}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Olive Oil}

\csvreader[
  separator=semicolon,
  before table=\sffamily\small,
  longtable={cp{10cm}rrr},
  table head={\toprule%
    \headentry{1.8cm}{PRODUCT\linebreak CODE}
    & \headentry{10cm}{PRODUCT NAME}
    & \headentry{1cm}{UNIT\linebreak SIZE}
    & \headentry{1cm}{PACK\linebreak SIZE}
    & \headentry{2.2cm}{WHOLESALE\linebreak UNIT PRICE}\\\midrule},
  late after line=\\\midrule,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
]
{./olive_oil_data.csv}
{Code=\code,Product Name=\name,Unit Size=\unitsize,Pack Size=\packsize,Unit Price=\unitprice}
{\code & \name & \unitsize & \packsize & \bfseries\unitprice}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's perfect. I knew LaTeX could do this but I think it was slightly beyond my current understanding. Thank you very much!