# Read csv files with spanish characters

Tags: tables, characters, input-encodings, csv, spanish

I'm new to latex and I'm trying to work on some tables for my thesis.

After some tryouts I've been able to import some CSV tables with the desired format but I'm struggling now with the content.

Let me give you an over view of how the code works. I've created my solution based on [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233424/recreating-formatting-of-an-excel-table-using-simplecsv).

This produces a result with which I'm quite happy:

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that whenever the cells contain some specific spanish characters, as for example: í, á, ó, ... latex triggers an error when compiling, and when I recompile again, it accepts the order but it produces a table with incomplete data.

Look at what happens when I change the 'a' in the random word from the first image into 'á'.

[image]

The tables that I will be importing (I need to importe a lot of them :P) will definetely include these characters and I don't know what to do. I've forced the CSV files to be coded as Unicode (UTF-8), so I don't understand why I'm having problem with these characters.

Any suggestion on how to fix this or simplify my code for generating tables will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot for your time and patience!

**EDITING TO ADD WORKING EXAMPLE**

On this example, if we create only the first table, everything works ok. If we try to create the second one, it throws a compilation error, and if you try to compile it again it produces a table with missing rows and characters on the changed fields. The changed fields are on cells [1, 0] & [2, 1] & [3, 2] of exampleTable3.csv

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
     a4paper,
     total={140mm,217mm},
     left=35mm,
     top=40mm,
 }
 \usepackage{longtable, array, booktabs}
 \usepackage{csvsimple}

 \begin{filecontents*}{exampleTable2.csv}
     Name;Description;Format;Restrictions
     Private;textext;boolean;optional
     Gender;some more field;string;optional
     Names;field;[array of String];restriction
     Facts;field;[array of Facts];optional
 \end{filecontents*}

 \begin{filecontents*}{exampleTable3.csv}
     Name;Description;Format;Restrictions
     Prívate;textext;boolean;optional
     Gender;some mòore field;string;optional
     Names;field;[arrày of String];restriction
     Facts;field;[array of Facts];optional
 \end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    %printing table 2, NO SPANISH SPECIAL characters
    \csvautobooklongtable[
       separator=semicolon
    ]
    {exampleTable2.csv}

    %printing table 3, YES SPANISH SPECIAL characters
    \csvautobooklongtable[
       separator=semicolon
    ]
    {exampleTable3.csv}

\end{document}
```

Adding an image of the result of the above code

[image]

**NEW EDIT: Adding example only on local**

I've been experimenting with my own example and I still can't make it work. On the next picture I show the source file used, the encoding of the source file at the bottom of the image and the outcome of each one of the tables.

It seems that this should be working, so I'm not really sure why it's not. Not playing with encodings of inputs files here, just all in the same source.

[image]

Thanks again for your help and input!

Comment: What are you using the create the CSV files? Excel for the Mac, for example, does not create utf8 CSV (even though it pretends to.)

Comment: I'm using microsoft excel (for windows) and forcing the format as displayed in this  [link](https://help.surveygizmo.com/help/encode-an-excel-file-to-utf-8-or-utf-16)

Comment: Ok. Can you turn your code into a compilable document rather than just some fragments. And also add a few sample rows of a CSV file that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that I could change the whole code encoding from \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} to something else, but I'm not really sure of what I should be using. Sorry, I'm not really used to encodings and I'm probably not explaining myself too well. The problem with the csv appears with any cell that has contents like: condició, col·lecció, pàgina. The cells with special characters get their contents trimmed. The rest of the latex document has no problem handling the characters.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is change the code you've put in *this question* so that it makes a complete compilable document that shows the error, and add a few lines of a sample CSV file that can be used with that code.  This is about the question, not about your actual document.  If we can replicate your problem, then we can probably solve it too.  But at the moment that's impossible.

Comment: Oh I see now. I had some problems trying to create this "working example" before posting the question. I can't invest more time on it now, I really need to  catch some sleep, but I'll do my best to create it tomorrow morning. Thanks anyways for your help @AlanMunn, I did not except that fast reply!

Comment: Ok, we'll wait for an update then. :)

Comment: Hi again, I've added a workign example, I've also been trying to solve it myself, but no luck so far. It seems that the way the document is configured it doesn't accept these accented and special characters like: ' or · or à or á

Comment: Thanks for adding your new example. It compiles properly for me, which makes me suspect that your source file isn't actually encoded utf8. I can replicate your problem only if the CSV file is latin1 and the document is utf8 (in which case the document compiles with errors, but if your editor pushes through, then you will get the output you show.)

Comment: After creating the file `exampleTable3.csv` as a real file, and not from `filecontents`, I get it working without any errors. You may have to delete the old file, or rename the new file.

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, but how is it possible that I'm getting the error generating the CSV even from the same source file as in the example? I've added a new image that displays the code, the result and the encoding of the source file.

Runar Trollet, I've been deleting the old files everytime I executed the example. How did you create the exampleTable3.csv? with which program/encoding? Sorry for being completely lost here guys

Comment: @SergiPorrasPagès Does your log file show any errors when you compile the file?

Comment: It produces the following warning, through which I can push through: ./sections/04/03_dataFormats.tex:47: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �nd (U+D3)
I've been able to make it work, downloading a CSV from googlespreadhseets, so pretty sure the problem is the encoding on my input files right?

Comment: Well it may be a bit of both. If your minimal example also gives those errors, the problem is that your *source* file isn't saved as utf8 (probably as latin1).  But yes, the problem is that the csv and the source file are different encodings.

Comment: I think your editor is lying to you. :) (Semi-serious: it's quite difficult to detect file encodings).  So make a brand new document, copy the text of your minimal example and save that as utf8. Does that still give you the error?

Comment: Hi @AlanMunn, it seems that as you mentioned it was the encodings all along. The minimal example was not working because it was generating UTF-8 CSV files instead of UTF-8 w/o BOM. After changing the encoding of those, the minimal example worked. Similarly, If I converted the excel files to that format or I downloaded .CSV files from googleSpreadhseets, they came with the format UTF-8 w/o BOM and everything worked. (If that makes sense). I feel stupid now for having had two horrible days because of this. I owe you big time. Any way I can commend you?

Comment: I can add an answer showing the issue, which you can then accept. Unfortunately you are not the first person to be caught by this problem. It's a constant pain for me  too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing comes from different encodings of your CSV files and your source file.  There are various ways that these encoding problems can arise, and it's very difficult for software to reliably detect the encoding of a file.

I was able to recreate the problem in the following way: I saved the minimal document with the `latin1` encoding (but left the `inputenc` option as `utf8`). Then the file produces errors like the following:

```
./csvsimple-latin1.tex:42: Package inputenc Error: Unicode char íva (U+E4)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Unfortunately a lot of editors push through the errors, and produce an output file anyway, which makes diagnosing the problem harder.

So the main issue is to make sure that the CSV file and your source document are the same encoding, and that the encoding is in fact the correct one. My experience with Excel for the Mac is that it doesn't actually produce UTF8 CSV files properly. Whether this is a problem with Windows versions of Excel I don't know. It's not surprising, though that you report that using CSV files from Google docs works, as they do seem to be valid UTF8.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. In the end, generating CSV files through a program different that microsoft excel (which let you control the encoding of the file to UTF-8 w/o BOM) worked fine. Thanks again for the help all along @Alan Munn! Hopefully I won't bother you guys anymore =)